# Importing data with Pyspark : Wrong datatype

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a problem with Pyspark : when I import my Dataset with Pyspark, all my columns are considered a string, even if my columns are numeric.

I don't have this probleme when I import data with Pandas.

I'm actually using a platform to devlop : Dataiku. the data are already on the platform and I import them with this code :

```
# Example: Read the descriptor of a Dataiku dataset
mydataset = 
dataiku.Dataset("Extracts___Retail_Master_Data___Product_Hierarchy_HDFS")
# And read it as a Spark dataframe
df = dkuspark.get_dataframe(sqlContext, mydataset)
```

I can't find a way to import my data into the correct format.

Thanks.

Comment: Please share some code, along with sample data; there are more than one ways for "importing" data to Spark (as RDD? as dataframe? as dataset?...), and it is completely unclear which one you are trying to use...

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I edited my question

Comment: Thanks, but I asked for some *sample data*, too; a `df.show(5)` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

In Dataiku there are 2 concepts: a storage type and a meaning. So when you explore your dataset you'll see both of them below each column name
(type in grey, meaning in blue)

[image]

A meaning is a type that Dataiku thinks suits the best according to what's stored in that column.

In your case you should go to your *Extracts___Retail_Master_Data___Product_Hierarchy_HDFS* dataset **settings** -> **schema** -> **set correct column types** -> **save**.

If you want to get more details there's a doc page

https://doc.dataiku.com/dss/latest/schemas/index.html